# Unable to bring up prometheus using docker-compose file. Always throws the error /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, docker-volume

I have been trying to bring up a Prometheus container using docker-compose file. I have looked into the various solutions available online and none of them seem to work. Please go through my prometheus.yaml file and the docker-compose.yml file and let me know, what have I configured wrongly.
My prometheus.yaml file is located at /root/prometheus/prometheus.yaml

Note: I'm trying to run the prometheus in the agent-mode and I'm running the docker-compose file from the /root path.

Error generated:

```
-bash-5.0# docker-compose up
[...]
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-12T14:28:25.350Z caller=main.go:447 level=error msg="Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml err="open /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml: no such file or directory"
prometheus exited with code 2
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  prometheus_data:
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.35.0
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml'
      - '--storage.agent.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      - '--enable-feature=agent'
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
```

Update 1: Adding the directory tree structure below

```
-bash-5.0# pwd
/root
-bash-5.0# tree
.
|-- cadvisor
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- docker-compose_1.yml
|-- prometheus
|   |-- prometheus.yaml
|   |-- prometheus.yml
|   |-- prometheus_old.yaml
|   `-- prometheus_old.yml
|-- prometheus.yaml
`-- prometheus.yml

1 directory, 9 files
-bash-5.0#
```

Update 2: I did some debugging and found out that the directory is being mounted, whereas the files are being mounted as directory.

Basically what I did was I made changes to the docker-compose.yml file as follows.

```
version: '3'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.35.0
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus-test/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      #- '--storage.agent.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      #- '--enable-feature=agent'
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
volumes:
  prometheus_data:
```

In the above docker file I'm mounting my prometheus.yml file to a different location and let the prometheus configure with default config file present.
Later I logged into the container and checked for the mounted files and this is what was seen.

```
-bash-5.0# docker container exec -it prometheus sh
/prometheus $ cd /etc
/etc $ ls -ltr
total 68
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         18774 Feb 10  2019 services
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           494 Aug 16  2019 nsswitch.conf
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           118 Mar 22 21:07 localtime
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           340 Apr 11 21:49 passwd
-rw-rw-r--    1 root     root           306 Apr 11 21:49 group
-rw-------    1 root     root           136 Apr 13 00:25 shadow
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root          4096 Apr 13 00:25 network
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Apr 15 10:54 ssl
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 May 13 10:54 mtab -> /proc/mounts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           174 May 13 10:54 hosts
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            13 May 13 10:54 hostname
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root            38 May 13 10:54 resolv.conf
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 13 11:00 prometheus-test
drwxr-xr-x    1 nobody   nobody        4096 May 13 11:00 prometheus
/etc $
/etc $ cd prometheus-test/
/etc/prometheus-test $ ls
prometheus.yml   
/etc/prometheus-test $ ls -ltr
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 13 10:54 prometheus.yml
/etc/prometheus-test $
```

From the above we can observe that the prometheus.yml file is being mounted as a directory instead of a file. Can anyone please let me know about this.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
This is a vm instance running on the ESXI server

```
-bash-5.0# docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.10
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        9424aeaee9
 Built:             Thu May 28 22:16:52 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.10
  Git commit:       633a0ea838f10e000b7c6d6eed1623e6e988b5bb
  Built:            Sat May  9 16:43:52 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.3.2
  GitCommit:        ff48f57fc83a8c44cf4ad5d672424a98ba37ded6
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:
-bash-5.0#
-bash-5.0#
-bash-5.0#
-bash-5.0# docker context ls
NAME                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT               KUBERNETES ENDPOINT   ORCHESTRATOR
default *           Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                         swarm
-bash-5.0#
```

Comment: There's some information missing here. Can you update your question to include the output of the `tree` command in the directory that contains your `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: The Prometheus server is unable to find `prometheus.yaml`. It's looking in `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml`. Your Compose maps `./prometheus:/etc/prometheus` i.e. A folder called `prometheus` in the working directory (`.`) to `/etc/prometheus`. I suspect you don't have a `prometheus` folder in the host's working directory or it doesn't contain `prometheus.yaml`. You either need to add a `prometheus` folder and move `prometheus.yaml` into it **before** restarting the Compose services **or** (as I tend to do) just change the mapping to `${PWD}/prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml`

Comment: **NB** Prometheus defaults to using `yml` for YAML files and you can save yourself some pain by using the same extension. If you rename the host file to `prometheus.yml`, then after correcting the reference to it in the Compose YAML file, you can drop the `--config.file` flag because the file will be in the default location.

Comment: @larsks Update the directory structure.

Comment: @DazWilkin I tried out the method as mentioned by you, looks like I'm encountering the error if I make use of the same." unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type"

Comment: Are you running `docker-compose` (and the docker client) on your Ubuntu VM? Or are you running it somewhere else and having it connect remotely to the Ubuntu VM?

Comment: @larsks I run it directly on my vm

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be over-complicating things. Given this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  prometheus_data:
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.35.0
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.agent.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries'
      - '--web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
      - '--enable-feature=agent'
```

And this directory structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
└── prometheus
    └── prometheus.yml
```

It Just Works:

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting prometheus ... done
Attaching to prometheus
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.206Z caller=main.go:187 level=info msg="Experimental agent mode enabled."
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.207Z caller=main.go:525 level=info msg="Starting Prometheus" version="(version=2.35.0, branch=HEAD, revision=6656cd29fe6ac92bab91ecec0fe162ef0f187654)"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.207Z caller=main.go:530 level=info build_context="(go=go1.18.1, user=root@cf6852b14d68, date=20220421-09:53:42)"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.207Z caller=main.go:531 level=info host_details="(Linux 5.17.5-100.fc34.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Apr 28 16:02:54 UTC 2022 x86_64 02da15afa8e7 (none))"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.207Z caller=main.go:532 level=info fd_limits="(soft=1073741816, hard=1073741816)"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.207Z caller=main.go:533 level=info vm_limits="(soft=unlimited, hard=unlimited)"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.208Z caller=web.go:541 level=info component=web msg="Start listening for connections" address=0.0.0.0:9090
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.208Z caller=main.go:1013 level=info msg="Starting WAL storage ..."
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.212Z caller=db.go:332 level=info msg="replaying WAL, this may take a while" dir=/prometheus/wal
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.213Z caller=tls_config.go:195 level=info component=web msg="TLS is disabled." http2=false
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.214Z caller=db.go:383 level=info msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=0 maxSegment=1
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.214Z caller=db.go:383 level=info msg="WAL segment loaded" segment=1 maxSegment=1
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.215Z caller=main.go:1034 level=info fs_type=XFS_SUPER_MAGIC
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.215Z caller=main.go:1037 level=info msg="Agent WAL storage started"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.215Z caller=main.go:1162 level=info msg="Loading configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.216Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=info remote_name=b4f547 url=http://10.120.23.224:9090/api/v1/write msg="Starting WAL watcher" queue=b4f547
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.216Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=info remote_name=b4f547 url=http://10.120.23.224:9090/api/v1/write msg="Starting scraped metadata watcher"
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.216Z caller=main.go:1199 level=info msg="Completed loading of configuration file" filename=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml totalDuration=809.925µs db_storage=275ns remote_storage=282.833µs web_handler=394ns query_engine=377ns scrape=211.707µs scrape_sd=43.033µs notify=609ns notify_sd=911ns rules=143ns tracing=1.98µs
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.216Z caller=main.go:930 level=info msg="Server is ready to receive web requests."
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:16.216Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=info remote_name=b4f547 url=http://10.120.23.224:9090/api/v1/write msg="Replaying WAL" queue=b4f547
prometheus    | ts=2022-05-13T12:12:22.558Z caller=dedupe.go:112 component=remote level=info remote_name=b4f547 url=http://10.120.23.224:9090/api/v1/write msg="Done replaying WAL" duration=6.341973747s
```

---

If this fails, the first diagnostic step is probably to remove the `command` section from `docker-compose.yaml` and add an `entrypoint` like this:

```
version: '3'
volumes:
  prometheus_data:
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.35.0
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus:/etc/prometheus
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    entrypoint:
      - sleep
      - inf
```

This will come up and just run `sleep`, allowing you to `docker-compose exec` into the container and explore the filesystem. If you find that `/etc/prometheus` is empty, that suggests that the you're not running `docker-compose` on the same system as the docker daemon (so when it attempts to reference a host path, like `./prometheus`, it doesn't find it).

Comment: The vm is located in my organization, is it possible that some restriction on the esxi is causing the mount to fail?

Comment: First, can you confirm whether or not the *exact* configuration presented here fails? If so, can you update your question to include the output of `docker version` and `docker context ls`?

Comment: I used the exact configuration provided by you. The docker threw the below error "Error loading config (--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml)" file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml err="read /etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml: is a directory". As suggested by you I removed the command section and added an entry point. Then I logged into the container to explore the file system. Turns out the prometheus.yml present in the /etc/prometheus/ path is a directory and not a yaml file. Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: /prometheus $ ls -ltr /etc/prometheus/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May 13 05:53 prometheus.yml

Comment: When you see a directory where you expected to see a file, this means that Docker wasn't able to find the source file (which goes to the questions I've asked in comments on your question, and the additional information I've asked for here).

Comment: I have updated the info in the question. I also found out that my /root folder links to the storage folder. I am not sure if this link is causing the issue. lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      12 Apr  1 15:48 root -> storage/root

Comment: -bash-5.0# readlink -f /root/docker-compose.yaml
/storage/root/docker-compose.yaml